# How to add the feature of Automatic OTP verification using Ionic framework?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I made an Ionic Cordova App & want to add the feature of **Automatic OTP verification which automatically retrieve the OTP from the message inbox & put digits into the input box of OTP.**

Here OTP is fired from the API to the phone.

**Prerequisites:- Installed SMS Retriever Plugins :** *1>ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sms-retriever-manager 2>npm install @ionic-native/sms-retriever*

**Can you suggest me any techniques on how will I implement this feature in the project**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible to achieve. These are the steps that you should follow to achieve it:

1 — Create a sample Ionic 4 app with dummy registration flow

2 — Implement Cordova plugin to read SMS (cordova-plugin-sms-receive)

3 — Build app on android or ios device

4 — Test automatic SMS read to approve a sample registration

```
declare var SMSReceive: any; // from Cordova-plugin
```

Then, you should add these events to your component:

1. SMSReceive.startWatch()
2. SMSReceive.stopWatch()
3. onSMSArrive

```
start() {
    SMSReceive.startWatch(
      () => {
        console.log('watch started');
        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e: any) => {
          var IncomingSMS = e.data;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(IncomingSMS));
        });
      },
      () => { console.log('watch start failed') }
    )
  }
```

And, Once you login:

```
SMSReceive.stopWatch(
() => { console.log('watch stopped') },
() => { console.log('watch stop failed') }
)
```

You can follow all the steps from the reference, I have attached to this answer.

SO is not a code writing, however, I can help you to give reference from [here](https://enappd.com/blog/automatically-read-sms-in-ionic-4-apps/42/) that is what I used for our application recently.